# finding the equation of a polynomial given its graph

Tags: polynomials

I have a graph of polynomial and I would like to know how to determine its equation.

Please, this isn't homework. What I'd like to do is actually reproduce this graph.

Thanks.

[image: graph]

Comment: Are you given points on the graph?

Comment: @RDizzl3 The only points I know are the x intercepts.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the points on the graph, either use newton's polynomial interpolation, or lagrange polynomial interpolation, I believe also if you make an approximation of the same (polynomial) degree, as your graph, then you should get a very accurate (if not exact) approximation.

Also the graph you have presented looks like a 6th order polynomial, so I would go with a 6th order interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

```
(x+4)*(x+2)*x*(x-2)*(x-4)*(x-6)*((x-8)**2+0.5**2)
```

comes close and has a nice structure.